# oAuth SSO on Liferay 6.2

Tags: oauth, liferay, single-sign-on, autologin, liferay-6.2

I need to integrate on Liferay 6.2 GA6 a SSO from a web application that provide info by oAuth

A native support doesn't exist.

My problem is to create the automatic login on Liferay (after the user creation or if the user already exists). Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override portal.properties adding

```
auto.login.hooks=com.yourpackage.hook.MyAutoLogin
```

Create the class:

```
package com.yourpackage.hook;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AutoLogin;
import com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AutoLoginException;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;

//based on example
// https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/liferay-examples/src/a41d71eba8f2fb2d4272a3ce8f393e77cec41d60/unsafe-login-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/src/br/brandizzi/adam/liferay/unsecure/UnsecureAutoLogin.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

public class MyAutoLogin implements AutoLogin {

    @Override
    public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String emailAddress = (String) session.getAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_EMAIL");

        if (emailAddress == null || emailAddress.isEmpty())
            return null;


            long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request);
            User user = null;
            try {
                user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyId, emailAddress);
            } catch (PortalException | SystemException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(request, "redirect");

            if (Validator.isNotNull(redirect)) {
                request.setAttribute(AutoLogin.AUTO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_AND_CONTINUE,PortalUtil.escapeRedirect(redirect));
            }


            String[] credentials = new String[3];

                                credentials[0] = String.valueOf(user.getUserId());
                                credentials[1] = user.getPassword();
                                credentials[2] = String.valueOf(user.isPasswordEncrypted());
                              //  credentials[2] =  Boolean.FALSE.toString();
        return credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] handleException(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1, Exception arg2)
            throws AutoLoginException {

        System.out.println("AutoLogin handleException ");

        return null;
    }
}
```

create an other class with the static methods:

```
public static JSONObject doSSO(String firstname, String surname,  String email,  String username,String accessToken, ActionRequest actionRequest,   ActionResponse actionResponse){

    JSONObject jsonResp = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

    //Get default Liferay company
     String webId = new String("liferay.com");
     Company company = null;
    try {
        company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByWebId(webId);
    } catch (PortalException | SystemException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("email "+email);

    User currentUser = null;
    try {
         currentUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(company.getCompanyId(), email);

    } catch (SystemException | PortalException e) {

        System.out.println("User to create");

    }

    if (Validator.isNull(currentUser)){

        long newUserId = 0;

        try {
            jsonResp = addNewUser( firstname,  surname,   email,   username );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String newUserIdS = jsonResp.getString("newUserId");
        newUserId = Long.valueOf(newUserIdS);

        try {
            currentUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.fetchUser(newUserId);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        notifyAuthorAboutInvited(email, currentUser);


    }

    setExistingUserOnSession( actionRequest,currentUser, accessToken);

    //Login the user
    HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest));
    HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(actionResponse);

    MyAutoLogin myLogin = new MyAutoLogin();
    try {
         myLogin.login(request, response);
         jsonResp.put("message","OK - User logged on Liferay");
    } catch (AutoLoginException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    //set Token on customfield
    //remember to set permission guest to view and update
     ServiceContext serviceContext = null;
    try {
        serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(User.class.getName(), actionRequest);
    } catch (PortalException | SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Map<String,Serializable> expandoBridgeAttributes = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
     expandoBridgeAttributes.put("token", accessToken);  
     serviceContext.setExpandoBridgeAttributes(expandoBridgeAttributes);
     currentUser.setExpandoBridgeAttributes(serviceContext);
    try {
        UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(currentUser);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String userToken =currentUser.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("token").toString();
    //System.out.println("doSSO accessToken dopo "+userToken);


    return jsonResp;
}
```

and:

```
private static void setExistingUserOnSession(ActionRequest actionRequest,User user, String accessToken) {

    HttpServletRequest req = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_EMAIL", user.getEmailAddress());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a hook where you create an AutoLogin class that extends BaseAutoLogin. Read the oAuth documentation and write a login logic in that hook, then set it in auto.login.hooks property in portal-ext.properties([properties reference](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Auto%20Login)). Then you will have to create a filter that extends BasePortalFilter and implemets processFilter method. You can model on CASFilter and CASAutologin

Comment: Just download Liferay source code and find the right classes i've described. The best way to expand Liferays functionality is just understand its source code. [source code link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.2.5%20GA6/liferay-portal-src-6.2-ce-ga6-20160112152609836.zip/download)

Comment: I found the code at https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs-all/src-html/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/CASAutoLogin.html#line.44. Thanks

Comment: I was able to develop my own AutoLogin without the use of filter. It works fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: How you did it @FilippoG ?